# mySQL query really slow when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization

I am having some issues trying to optimize a query that is using the GROUP BY function.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, snapshot_id, date_sent, subject, name
FROM snapshots
INNER JOIN brands
ON snapshots.brand_id = brands.brand_id
WHERE snapshots.status = 1 AND brands.status = 1
GROUP BY subject
ORDER BY date_sent DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Two Tables

```
[Table: snapshots]
snapshot_id   subject   date_sent   brand_id   status
1             abc       2015-2-1    1          1
2             abc       2015-2-2    1          1
3             xyz       2015-2-3    2          1
4             xyz       2015-2-4    2          1
5             xyz       2015-2-5    3          1

[Table: brands]
brand_id      name      status
1             nike      1
2             adidas    1
3             puma      1
```

Result:

```
count   snapshot_id   date_sent   subject   name
2       1             2015-2-1    abc       nike
2       3             2015-2-3    xyz       adidas
1       5             2015-2-5    xyz       puma
```

The query without the limit returns 70K+ records.
When executing without the Group, the query returns without any issue.
When executing with the Group by subject, the query is painfully slow.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you create the tables? Any indexes includes? With a `GROUP BY` clause the database has to search for _all_ entries - if you run the query without `GROUP BY` the database will probably return records by and by while you are browsing them.

Comment: Most likely an index `ALTER TABLE snapshots ADD KEY(subject,date_sent )`  will speed it up,if its not there already.

Comment: Show your indexes and the EXPLAIN result. Your mixing of aggregate and non-aggregate results seems odd.

Comment: @Mihai, that worked. For future reference and for me to get better. What should I look for when creating indexes? How do i know which column(s) should be included in an index?

Comment: Composed index on all the columns in the WHERE united by AND,composed index on GROUP BY and ORDER BY Columns,in the order they appear provided they are in the same table.THere are many things,learn about cardinality and what an index actually is.Spend some time reading that boring documentation and try to understand it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html USe the explain plan.